# Python (Regex: Replacing Every Character After a Single Letter)

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I'm looking to match all strings in a Pandas column. The strings are in a similar format.

```
9201 AVENUE B - GROUND FL REAR
56-58 AVENUE B STORE #2
9201 AVENUE B - GROUND FL REAR
1315 AVENUE C
431 WEST AVENUE D BASEMENT UNIT
12334 Avenue Z Store
```

Essentially I want to remove character after the single letter that follows "Avenue" (i.e. everything after Avenue C).

```
9201 AVENUE B
56-58 AVENUE B
9201 AVENUE B
1315 AVENUE C
431 WEST AVENUE D
12334 Avenue Z
```

I have this current code:

```
r"AVENUE\s([^A-Z].*)", ''
```

However, the code is failing to replace everything that comes after the letter. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Use `re.sub(r"\b(AVENUE\s+[A-Z]).*", r"\1", text, flags=re.I)`

Comment: You're replacing everything, not just what comes after it.

Comment: Why do you have `^` in `[^A-Z]`. That prevents it from matching the letter after `AVENUE`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
re.sub(r"\b(AVENUE\s+[A-Z]).*", r"\1", text, flags=re.I)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rggYK0/1) and the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/QP1CJn):

```
import re
strs = ['9201 AVENUE B - GROUND FL REAR', '56-58 AVENUE B STORE #2', '9201 AVENUE B - GROUND FL REAR', '1315 AVENUE C', '431 WEST AVENUE D BASEMENT UNIT', '12334 Avenue Z Store ']
for s in strs:
    print(re.sub(r"\b(AVENUE\s+[A-Z]).*", r"\1", s, flags=re.I))
# => [9201 AVENUE B, 56-58 AVENUE B, 9201 AVENUE B, 1315 AVENUE C, 431 WEST AVENUE D, 12334 Avenue Z]
```

The pattern matches:

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(AVENUE\s+[A-Z])` - Group 1 (the value is referred to with the `\1` placeholder from the replacement pattern):

  - `AVENUE` - a literal string
  - `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
  - `[A-Z]` - an ASCII letter
- `.*` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars as many as possible.

**NOTE**: the `re.I` flag will make the `[A-Z]` case insensitive. To avoid that, use `re.sub(r"\b((?i:AVENUE)\s+[A-Z]).*", r"\1", s)`, see [this Python demo](https://ideone.com/1Q35VW).

Comment: Works perfectly. I inputed it into my existing str.replace. Thank you so much. Was stuck on that for a bit .

Comment: Hi follow question if possible. i also have address like 888 Avenue Store. I want to keep the 888 Avenue but get rid of everything behind it. I've played around with the regex code but I ended up getting rid of the streets that I want to keep (i.e 9201 Avenue B ). How can I do both ?   I know moving the group () helps

Comment: @ynnad Use a word boundary, `r'\b(AVENUE\s+[A-Z])\b.*'`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/rggYK0/3)

Answer (score 1):

Your regexp matches everything starting with `AVENUE` followed by a non-letter, and replaces all of that with the empty string. So it removes the whole thing when it matches.

You can use a [lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to match the remainder of the line when it's preceded by `AVENUE <letter>`, but not include that in the match.

```
re.sub(r"(?<=AVENUE [A-Z]).*", "", text)
```

Answer (score 0):

With pandas you can do str replace

`df[col].str.replace('((?<=AVENUE [A-Z]).*)', '')`

```
0        9201 AVENUE B
1       56-58 AVENUE B
2        9201 AVENUE B
3        1315 AVENUE C
4    431 WEST AVENUE D
5       12334 AVENUE Z
```